# Use terraform with Azure or AWS and with custom UI definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, terraform, devops, azure-rm-template

I am looking for a way to create a custom UI definition, which I will use with Terraform to create resources and the terraform arguments/parameters will be provided from the UI. Basically the requirement is like

- Creating a customized UI and pass parameters from there ex: Name for Web App Service
- Deploy a Web App using terraform which requires name argument and it'll come from the UI input

I'm thinking if that is possible with Azure or AWS.

Comment: Not sure about the terraform, but you can do it with CloudFormation. define a parameter and feed the UI parameter value in it. Then deploy the stack with CloudFormation libraries like boto3 for Python

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking if that is possible with Azure or AWS.

Yes, its possible with Azure and AWS, or any other cloud provider. Obviously you have to develop a fully custom web application for that with backend running and managing your TF. There is no read-made tools for that.

Comment: Why do i need a web application managing my TF ? If I use AWS cloud formation I can define parameter in the UI and pass it while deploying, I want something same but using TF not cloud formation for cross compatibility

Comment: @KaziRahiv You are asking about Terraform, not cloudformation. So what cloudformation has to do with your question?

Comment: Yes, I said it for example. In cloud formation I can define UI for user parameters also with deployment instructions. My question is if that is possible solely with Terraform.

Comment: @KaziRahiv I answered "There is no read-made tools for that.". TF is not part of AWS nor Azure. You have to develop your own custom solution for that UI if you want.